# c# rgb colour scale

Tags: c#, rgb

I have a requirement to display a particular colour representation dependant upon data.  At one end of the scale is green and the other red.  The scale should cover the colours in between.

I am comfortable with the actual programming, but unsure of how to scale the rgb colours.  Does anybody know any scales for this sort of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following method should work for you :

```
    Color GetColor(Int32 rangeStart /*Complete Red*/, Int32 rangeEnd /*Complete Green*/, Int32 actualValue)
    {
        if (rangeStart >= rangeEnd) return Colors.Black;

        Int32 max = rangeEnd - rangeStart; // make the scale start from 0
        Int32 value = actualValue - rangeStart; // adjust the value accordingly

        Int32 green = (255 * value) / max; // calculate green (the closer the value is to max, the greener it gets)
        Int32 red = 255 - green; // set red as inverse of green

        return Color.FromRgb((Byte)red, (Byte)green, (Byte)0);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you mean?

```
Color GetColor(int scale)
{
    // scale is between 1 and 255
    return Color.FromArgb(255, scale, 255 - scale, 0);
}
```

Comment: suggested to use `byte scale` instead of `int scale` as scale is 1-255.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a linear scale, you might find you get the message across more clearly with a little colour theory. Depending on how much time you want to spend, you might also want to look at e.g.

[Cynthia Brewer](http://www.infovis.net/printMag.php?num=184&lang=)

[Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com)

[Stanford lecture on Colour for visualization](http://hci.stanford.edu/courses/cs448b/w09/lectures/20090209-Color.pdf)

among many, many others -- google for Processing and data visualization too.

Comment: How does this answer the question? These suggest alternates schemes, not how to implement a scale from red to green.

Comment: "The scale should cover the colours in between." There are a *lot* of ways of covering that space, and some happen to be better than others at helping people visualize data. For example -- for a temperature plot a linear scale might work well. However, if you want to emphasize that a value somewhere near the middle is very important, you might want a contrasting colour in that region. The data you're visualizing and the message you want to get across should determine the way you vary the colour between two endpoints.

Comment: and +1 to Cody for rightly calling out a slightly vague answer.